# Not able to force language to be RTL?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue getting the test in Arabic going RTL. It is on a word document and on the word document the text is RTL. However, when I transfer the text to the site, that is when it does not behave the way it does on the text.

Below is the text that is already in RTL and as you can see, it is not behaving the way it should:

> إننا نقدم خدمات المترجم الفوري المجانية للإجابة عن أي أسئلة تتعلق
> بالصحة أو جدول الأدوية لدينا. للحصول على مترجم فوري، ليس عليك سوى
> الاتصال بنا على Los Angeles: 1-855-464-3571.  San Diego:
> 1-855-464-3572. سيقوم شخص ما يتحدث العربية بمساعدتك. هذه خدمة مجانية.

I have done the following css to make it rtl:

`<bdo dir="rtl">` and `direction:rtl.`

When I do that, it does put the text in order by the words themselves are filpped.

Is there some special code or a software that is free to behave the way it should?

Comment: I've never worked with Arabic, but what's wrong with this? https://jsfiddle.net/b2zxn3ro/

Comment: @AndyHolmes The issue with that is you see the text "إننا" should be reversed, meaning the little weird comma underneath the l should be the first word on the left hand side on the sentence

Comment: Gotcha, you'd expect it to work properly wouldn't you :/

Comment: @AndyHolmes Well I expect to reflect how it is read in the language. Is there software out there that can reflect how it is based on the language?